# Configuration of dockerized applications

Tags: docker

How do you deal with host-specific configuration for docker containers?

Most importantly production passwords. They can't be put to container for security reasons. Also, they need to be changed on regular basis w/o redeploying anything.

Comment: when you run your container, you can pass it with `-e pass=abcdef`, see the run syntax http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#run

Answer (score 1):

I mostly use Volume containers if I really want to avoid making an image for that: http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/

however, I have done things like

```
FROM myapp
ADD password.file /etc
RUN do some cfg
```

to make specific images with password baked in.

That way the specific configuration list passwords is not in the general images which are re-used and known, but they are in an image that is build for and on the host that is running it. (this approach is not really very different to using puppet/chef etc to customise the files on a vm/server - it eventually needs to hit the filesystem in a safe, but repeatable way)

Comment: Bad idea to bake passwords into an image. I assume you never push the image into a shared repository? That's the big danger ... a shared image would result in each container instance using the same unencrypted credential (also possible to read it straight out of the image)....  Chef is not the same, it supports encrypted data bags (and vaults) to keep secrets safe at rest. I assume Puppet is the same.

Comment: I never push an image from a server to a registry. but yes, you always have to work out how to mitigate the risks in your workflow.

Answer (score 1):

As one comment says, use environment variables you can pass via `-e pass=abcdef`. You can also save them in a fig.yml config file to avoid having to type them every time.

Comment: Also if you use Kubernetes there are secrets: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/secrets/

Comment: Using environment variables to pass secrets is officially considered a **bad idea**. Quoting from [Secrets: write-up best practices, do's and don'ts, roadmap](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/13490): "Features / hacks that are (mis)used for secrets: environment variables, build-time environment variables, mark .. squash / flatten layers, volumes, manually building containers, custom hack".